# TSQL Filter Rows with invalid characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with what is supposed to be a list of Active directory users. In many cases they have invalid characters in the name

I need to have a query that will select only those that have a user name that doesn't contain

any of these characters.

```
"\/[]:;|=,+*?<>
```

something like

`select username from userlist where username not like regex`

I see how I can easily filter one of those but not sure how to look for any of them.

Comment: username not like '%\%' and username not like '%/%' and so on...

Comment: T-SQL has no regular expressions. You can use `LIKE` with a pattern matching the characters you want to exclude, eg `WHERE UserName NOT LIKE '%["\/[]:;|=,+*?<> ]%'`. The pattern `[...]` matches a single instance of any of the characters inside the square brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like :

```
WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%["\/:;|=,+*?<>]%' 
   OR CHARINDEX('[', MyColumn) > 0
   OR CHARINDEX(']', MyColumn) > 0
```

Should work to find abnormal rows

Answer (score 0):

You can roll it all into a single `like` by using an *escape character*:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Val NVarChar(32) );
insert into @Samples ( Val ) values
  ( '[' ), ( ']' ), ( '"' ),
  ( 'a\b/c:d;e|f=g,h+i*j?k<l>m' ),
  ( 'Vogon poetry.' );

-- Undesirable characters: "\/[]:;|=,+*?<>

select Val, case when Val like N'%["\/[↕]:;|=,+*?<>]%' escape N'↕' then 'Fail' else 'Pass' end as Status
  from @Samples;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q5FDONN_).